# looping and casting problem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, casting

I've got following method in `User` model

```
  def get_employees
    @employees = []
      groups.each do |i|
        @employees << Group.find(i).employees
      end
      @employees
  end
```

This is what the console prints when I call this method:

```
> >> User.find(4).get_employees
> => [[#<Employee id: 4, first_name: "test", last_name: "test1",
> email_address: "test@gmail.com",
> created_at: "2010-08-25 04:23:02",
> updated_at: "2010-08-25 04:23:02">,
> #<Employee id: 5, first_name: "hello", last_name: "hello1", email_address:
> "hello@gmail.com", created_at:
> "2010-08-25 04:51:37", updated_at:
> "2010-08-25 04:51:37">]]
```

however, the following code does not work:

```
>> @user.get_employees.each{|i| p i.first_name}
NoMethodError: undefined method `first_name' for #<Class:0x9e372f0>
```

What do I need to do in order to get the `first_name` of the `employees` from the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Group.find(i).employees` call returns an array, so your `get_employees` method is returning an array of arrays. Replacing the last line of `get_employees` with `@employees.flatten!` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that the variable i is still an array. You declare @employee as an empty array and you insert another array which is what is returned by Group.find(i).employees.

i[0] should contain:

```
#<Employee id: 4, first_name: "test", last_name: "test1",
> email_address: "test@gmail.com",
> created_at: "2010-08-25 04:23:02",
> updated_at: "2010-08-25 04:23:02">,
> #<Employee id: 5, first_name: "hello", last_name: "hello1", email_address:
> "hello@gmail.com", created_at:
> "2010-08-25 04:51:37", updated_at:
> "2010-08-25 04:51:37">
```

Answer (score 0):

As the previous poster noted, you've got an array within an array. Why recreate some logic that is already built into rails? I would have done something like this in the user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups
  has_many :employees, :through => :groups
end
```

Then you can just do `User.employees`

Comment: I can not do this...because the way I am getting groups in User model is: `has_many :departments   has_many :groups, through => :departments`  now I can not do `has_many :employees, :through => :groups`

Comment: there is a similar question along this type of model on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568528/how-to-manage-3-many-to-many-models-in-rails